# How to get stream onAuthStateChanged with firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I use flutter plugin firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1

I get this warning in editor:

> The function expression type 'String Function(FirebaseUser)' isn't of
> type 'String Function(User)'. This means its parameter or return type
> doesn't match what is expected. Consider changing parameter type(s) or
> the returned type(s).

```
FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged =>
      _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map((FirebaseUser user) => user?.uid);
```

Also the 'onAuthStateChanged' is deprecated.
How to change it to get stream on onAuthStateChanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged =>
      _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map((FirebaseUser user) => user?.uid);
```

into this:

```
FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged =>
      _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((User user) => user?.uid);
```

You need to use `User` class instead of `FirebaseUser`.